# Why did this previously valid CSS suddenly become an unknown directive?

Tags: css, webmatrix-3

I had the following CSS in an old web site:

```
@-o-keyframes rainbowGlow {
from {
         color: whitesmoke;
     }
13% {
        color: red;
    }
25% {
        color: orange;
    }
38% {
        color: yellow;
    }
50% {
        color: green;
    }
63% {
        color: blue;
    }
75% {
        color: indigo;
    }
88% {
        color: violet;
    }
to {
       color: white;
   }
}
```

Trying to use it in a new website, though, using the same CSS, I now get, "*Validation (CSS 3.0): "-o-keyframes" is not a known '@' directive.*"

Why? How to rectify?

Comment: Vendor prefixes are never valid CSS - a more charitable validator would suppress any errors relating to vendor prefixes, however. W3C Jigsaw provides that option, but I don't know if Visual Studio does (and I generally don't trust a validator that calls it "CSS 3.0" to start with).

Comment: Because `-o-keyframes` is not a standard at-rule, but a user agent's experimental rule. There's nothing to fix.

Comment: And to be honest, opera uses blink now, so you don't need the prefixes anymore either.

Comment: @somethinghere: AFAIK, Blink still requires prefixes for animations - the only layout engine to still do so. Even the last version of Opera to use Presto doesn't.

Comment: @BoltClock Waw thats the only exception? I mean, blink doesn't do prefixes for anything but that than. Goof to know. I do know you still need the -webkit- prefix for just about anything for decent safari support.